# Printing an array based on specific values in a column

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, conditional-statements

Have a 2d array with this column and index.

```
data = np.array([1, 7, 3, 6, 2, 8, 5, 9, 4]).reshape(3,3)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'], columns = ['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

I'm trying to display the array where any value of column a is less than 6. End result should show the full array without row 2, but needs to be based on the 'a' less than 6 condition.

Couple of avenues I've tried.

```
print(np.less(df,df['a']<6))
print(np.where(df['a'] < 6,df))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [df.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

```
df.loc[df.a < 6]

       a  b  c
One    1  7  3
Three  5  9  4
```